# Fullcalendar days background color upon ajax data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar

Im using fullcalendar and i need to paint the background color of some days upon an ajax request.

I have some classrooms and they can be busy or free, so i want to paint the background color of the day cell matching if the classroom is free or not.

I know how to change events colors but i dont know how to do it with the day cells, i also know that this function is called when days are rendered:

```
dayRender: function (date, cell) {
            console.log(cell[0].dataset.date);
        }
```

So i could have a javascript array with the days that have to be marked as busy, but how do i update that array when the user changes of month?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
viewRender: function(view,element){
                $.ajax({
                    url: //your custom url,
                    data: {start:view.start.format(),end:view.end.format()},
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: "json",
                    contentType: "application/json",                
                    success: function (data) {
                        $.each(data, function(i) {
                            $('.fc-day[data-date="'+data[i]    ["date"]+'"]').css('background', Your Color Code);
                        });
                    }
                });
            },
```